# Change visibility on cells in ssrs report based on whether the child group of the parent group is visible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, grouping, ssrs-2012

I am wondering if there is a way to toggle visibility of a row or cell based on if child group is visible in the report.  I have a report designed similar to this:

[image]

I have it set to toggle the visibility based on the parent group like in that photo and have a static line that shows the total when child group is not visible / toggled.  Is there a way I can make the value in that static line hidden when the child group is toggled? Below example shows when toggled but the total line shows when child toggled.  I am trying to make this blank when the child group is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the visibility of the cell or cells you want to toggle in the same way as you set the row visibility except you want it to default to "Show". If you set the "Display can be toggled by this report item" to the same textbox as you the row toggle it should work.